# Check if parameter is missed

Tags: function, powershell, alias

I have this code in my $profile in PS version 5:

```
function af_ {
   Get-ChildItem function: | findstr.exe $args 
   if (! $args) {
     return "nothing"
   }
}
```

Calling e.g.

```
af_ tgit
```

Return:

```
Function        tgit                                               0.7.3      posh-git
```

Calling

```
af_
```

Output:

```
FINDSTR: Syntaxfehler
nothing
```

Two questions:

1. How can I check if $args is not empty without "Syntaxfehler" (this is german..)?
2. Can I improve my idea to get the defnition of a custom function, as would be

   `declare -f $function`

in Bash. It shows the definition which seems not possible in PS. I have to process the function: device and then look for the "Definition" output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the syntax error because you call `findstr.exe` with the empty argument *before* checking it. Reversing the order should do it:

```
function af_ {
   if (! $args) {
     return "nothing"
   }
   Get-ChildItem function: | findstr.exe $args 
}
```

As for your second question you can use `Get-Command` to get the command and it's definition:

```
(Get-Command af_).Definition
```